# simple numerical compare in zsh function always true

Tags: shell, zsh

I want to do something randomly in my shell. I've boiled my issue down to this embarrassingly simple thing:

```
dice-roll() {
    local THRESHOLD=50
    #local DICE_ROLL=$[${RANDOM}%100]
    local DICE_ROLL=40

    if  ((DICE_ROLL -ge THESHOLD)); then
        echo "win: threshold is $THRESHOLD , rolled $DICE_ROLL"
    else
        echo "loss: rolled $DICE_ROLL"
    fi
}
```

I always win.  Why?

Comment: I get an error for that snippet. What version of zsh do you have? You have a typo in the test `THESHOLD` is missing the `R`. Using `set -x` would have found this for you (or at least pointed you in the right direction).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrong syntax, plus typing error in the variable name. It should be

```
 ((DICE_ROLL >= THRESHOLD))
```

or

```
[[ DICE_ROLL -ge THRESHOLD ]]
```